# $Var(f(X))$ when $Var(X)\to 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

I am a newcomer to measure-theoretic probability theory, and I have some confusion with how the notion of variance is handled in this framework. Intuitively speaking, for a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and a random variable $X$, if $Var(X)=0$, then $Var(f(X))$ should be $0$, and when $Var(X)\to 0$, the same should happen to $Var(f(X))$. However, mathematically there seems to be some intricate issues involved with this intuition. For example, let's take $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. The variance of $f(X)$ is defined by
$$Var(f(X))=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx - (\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx)^2$$
Two issues:

1. $Var(f(X))$ is simply undefined when $\sigma=0$!!
2. When we let $\sigma\to0$, by dominated convergence and with some manipulations, we can see that $Var(f(X))$ approaches $0$. See, for example: [Proof that the limit of the normal distribution for a standard deviation approximating 0 is the dirac delta function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072415/proof-that-the-limit-of-the-normal-distribution-for-a-standard-deviation-approxi). But this only works for $f$ belonging to the Schwartz space. So I am quite confused about this limitation, since we are restricted to such a small class of measurable functions, while intuitively $Var(f(X))$ should go to $0$ as $Var(X)\to 0$ for any $f$ that's not "crazily behaving".

Now I am very confused about how variance in measure-theoretic probability works. When we talk about $\lim_{Var(X)\to0}Var(f(X))$, are we really stuck with $f$ being a Schwartz function? What about issue 1.? Any help on clearing my confusion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by crazily behaving. I believe that $f(x)=1/x$ and $f(x)=\exp(\exp(x))$ definitely are counterexamples. I think there are also examples (different distributions) such that $f(x)=x^p$ for a certain $p>1$ doesn't work.

Comment: I am really just inquiring if we are really just restricted to having $f$ belonging to the Schwartz space, for at least my example of taking $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: In that case my intuition tells it should work due to dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

For your first point, your formula for variance (and analogs for expectation) holds when the law of $X$ arises from the density $f$ (with respect to Lebesgue measure). There are more general definitions of expectation and variance than the ones you have given. If $\sigma=0$, then $X$ is a degenerate random variable i.e. constant with probability one. It follows that $X$ does not have a density with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Ah I see, yes I was suspecting that issue 1. can be easily dealt with. I am really curious about how issue 2. is handled. And, thank you for the helpful answer.